# Codenameone:Remove sidemenubar from screen(form)

Tags: codenameone

I want to remove `sideMenuBar` dynamically when my form(screen) loads. currently I am removing commands using `removeAllCommands()` method. but this is not fine for me I just want to remove whole `sideMenuBar`.
 Can you please let me how to resolve it?

Comment: The question is unclear. You need to explain what you are actually trying to achieve why the existing approach didn't work (what happened when you did that) and ideally provide screenshots. You also need to indicate if you are using the `Toolbar` or `SideMenuBar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you are really asking but I'm guessing you are looking for `SideMenuBar.closeCurrentMenu()`.